# Run node inspector with mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, node-inspector

I can't seem to debug mocha scripts.

I am able to run node with inspector like this `node --inspect script.js`. This then gives me a url to go to to debug, something like `chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/...`

However, when I use mocha with this line `mocha --inspect test.js` I am not able to debug. It says 'Debugger listening on [::]:5858'. Is there any way for me to debug a mocha test using node's inspector?

Going to localhost:5858 gives me this info:

```
Type: connect
V8-Version: 5.1.281.84
Protocol-Version: 1
Embedding-Host: node v6.9.1
Content-Length: 0
```

Using `--inspect --debug-brk` doesn't help.

Comment: using `node-inspector` might work. But node native `--inspect` is definitely better. Waiting for a solution

Comment: Try with `node --inspect --debug-brk script.js`: this should set a breakpoint at the first line of the script, giving you time to open the DevTools panel.

Comment: @MarcoL Tried --debug-brk but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you copy and paste that URL (`chrome-devtools-etc...`) in the browser?

Comment: This is awesome. Testing is so cutting edge that we don't need an inspector. Don't you miss PHP-style debugging with echo and print all over the place? This is progress!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem was my version of mocha. I was running a  version older than 3.1.0. `--inspect` support was added in [3.1.0](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#310--2016-09-27)

I am now able to run with debugging with these lines:

```
mocha --reporter spec --inspect test.js
mocha --reporter spec --inspect-brk test.js
```

Answer (score 4):

> [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --inspect --debug-brk` is
>   deprecated. Please use `node --inspect-brk` instead.

use in the future

```
mocha --reporter spec --inspect-brk test.js
```